# Default method returns true for a while, and then returns false? (Possible JVM bug)

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, java-8

I have an issue with the following code, which I isolated to the most closed form, I am using Java 8, which is almost ready for launch (18 March 2014), so I expect no serious issues in the implementation itself, so it may/must be my own code:

**Note: The code is written in Java 8, which has all kinds of new features, including `default` method implementation in interfaces.**

```
public abstract class Drawable implements DrawableInterface {    

}
```

---

```
interface DrawableInterface {
    default public boolean isShadowReceiver() {
        return false;
    }

    default public boolean isShadowCaster() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface ShadowDrawable extends DrawableInterface {
    @Override
    default public boolean isShadowReceiver() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    default public boolean isShadowCaster() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Box extends Drawable implements ShadowDrawable {

}
```

---

```
public class IsolatedBug {
    private final Box box;

    private final List<Drawable> drawables;

    public IsolatedBug() {
        this.box = new Box();
        this.drawables = new ArrayList<>();

        drawables.add(box);
        drawables.forEach(drawable -> System.out.println(drawable + " C=" + drawable.isShadowCaster() + "/R=" + drawable.isShadowReceiver()));
    }

    private void init() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            drawables.forEach(drawable -> System.out.println(drawable + " C=" + drawable.isShadowCaster() + "/R=" + drawable.isShadowReceiver()));
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new IsolatedBug().init();
    }
}
```

The code in itself may not make most sense, but that is because I have stripped a load of other irrelevant methods.

However, when you observe the output, you see something strange, at a certain point, for me personally after 30 seconds, I see the following:

> isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=true/R=true
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=true/R=true
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=true/R=true
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=true/R=true
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=false/R=false
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=false/R=false
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=false/R=false
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=false/R=false
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=false/R=false
>   isolatedbug.Box@5acf9800 C=false/R=false

The time when it switches from `true` to `false`, seems to depend on the number of calls the method, as with longer sleeps in between, it takes longer to switch.

I am running this, for full information on Windows 8 64-bit, with as `java -version`:

> java version "1.8.0"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b129)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b69, mixed mode)

Can anyone explain to me what is going on?
I'd also appreciate if others with Java 8 -any build-, could run and see if they have the same issue.

Some more information after using this code:

```
  Properties p = System.getProperties();
  p.list(System.out);
```

Output:

```
-- listing properties --
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin
java.vm.version=25.0-b69
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=;
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.script=
user.country=NL
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\Users\Frank\Dropbox\NetbeansProjec...
java.runtime.version=1.8.0-b129
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\li...
os.arch=amd64
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.variant=
os.name=Windows 8.1
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:...
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=52.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version=6.3
user.home=C:\Users\Frank
user.timezone=
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding=UTF-8
java.specification.version=1.8
user.name=Beheerder
java.class.path=C:\Users\Frank\Dropbox\NetbeansProjec...
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
sun.arch.data.model=64
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre
sun.java.command=isolatedbug.IsolatedBug
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.language=nl
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.version=1.8.0
java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\li...
sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\li...
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
```

I have also checked the `-Xint` VM option, when this has been used, it returns `true` as expected.

So the conclusion seems to be that in my particular use case, the interpreted and JIT compiled/inlined variants of the code are not the same and hence it is a possibility that after the interpreted code is compiled it switches from interpreted to compiled and thus clarifying the switch in output.

Adding the `-Xint` option to the actual program in which the bug occured, has also fixed the issue there.

**The official bug report has been accepted: [JIRA Bug JDK-8036100](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036100?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel)**

Comment: how can your interface have a concrete implementation of the methods?

Comment: @Leo Read up on Java 8 please.

Comment: Good one... I think you should edit the post subject for more clarity (edit: something like "Java 8: inconsistent behaviour of interface default methods?")

Comment: Can the problem be narrowed down further, e.g. by removing the `List` and the new `forEach`, and by only including one default method in your interface? Ideally, it should be able to demonstrate this by `BuggyOverride buggy = ...; int i = 0; while (buggy.heisenbug()) i++; System.out.println("B0rked after " + i + " iterations");`

Comment: @skiwi I agree, they should be usable. But I do not think they are a good idea in the first place. I see an Interface as a contract, which when you implement you sign and by singing it you agree to provide your own implementation of these methods. These defaults open a door for people to implement only part of an interface in their class and when someone else tries to use that class - boom default behaviour, and you were left with the false assumption that that interface was **really** implemented

Comment: @MarioStoilov Look into Scala's 'traits'. It is apparently one of the most useful features of Scala. Default implementations is a step in that direction and I've come up with plenty of use cases for them already. If they don't fit *you*, just don't use them. But complaining about them to others just because isn't very useful.

Comment: With *Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b128)* I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Bart What Hotspot version are you using, a JIRA/blog is claiming that Hotspot VM is at fault.

Comment: @skiwi - from the Jira, it was resolved in: *JDK-8032966  8   Vladimir Ivanov  P1  Closed  Fixed  b127*

Comment: Although, I reproduced it with *Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b129)*

Comment: You can rule out (or confirm) a JIT bug by passing the VM the `-Xint` argument when launching. This disables JIT compilation entirely.

Comment: @ntoskrnl I'll try that later today then.

Comment: Using *Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b69, mixed mode)*. Same as mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Bart I changed the sleep time from 1000ms to 100ms in the question, to reflect my own tests.

Comment: @skiwi Well, I already testen on both intervals. First 1000ms for 5 minutes and 100ms for another 5 minutes. Same result.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg If you can be bothered, could you please give an example of a use case that you've came up with ? Genuine question.

Comment: @MarioStoilov "[implementing] only part of an interface" is the whole point. It's no different from someone implementing an abstract class where only some of the methods in the class are abstract (aside from the potential multiple inheritance issues default implementations in interfaces could cause, but I don't know if Java 8 will allow that).

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Take a look at [this interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html). Now think of how many of those methods could have a default implementation.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Another use case: The [Delayed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html) interface extends `Comparable<Delayed>` but the documentation states that "An implementation of this interface must define a compareTo method that provides an ordering consistent with its getDelay method.", this would be perfect for a default method.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is a known bug in Java8.

See this Jira: [CHA ignores default methods during analysis leading to incorrect code generation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031695)

[This blog entry is enlightening](http://johnthecodingarchitect.blogspot.ca/2014/01/major-bug-with-java-8-default-methods.html)....

### Update / Summary:

- issue identified before b127, and fixed in b127 ( [JDK-8031695](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031695) )
- issue reappeared (or a similar issue appeared) in b129 ( [JDK-8036100](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036100) )
- issue has been 'worked around' ([disable the optimization that was failing](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/hsx/hotspot-main/hotspot/rev/e46f2ee62e78)) in b132 ( [available here](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) )
- issue also logged for a 'proper' fix for later ( [JDK-8036153](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036153) )

---

### Previous Notes

I have reproduced this issue with:

Claims that this issue is resolved in b127 are confusing since I see it clearly in b129 (unless I am confused about the JVM version conventions...)

> ```
> C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\bin>java -version
> java version "1.8.0"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b129)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b69, mixed mode)
>
> C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\bin>
> ```

Adding System.out.println(System.getProperties());

> ```
> {
> java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, 
> java.runtime.version=1.8.0-b129, 
> java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, 
> java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 
> java.vm.version=25.0-b69, 
> java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, 
> java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, 
> java.vm.specification.version=1.8, 
> java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, 
> java.specification.version=1.8, 
> java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, 
> java.class.version=52.0, 
> sun.boot.library.path=C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\jre\bin, 
> sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, 
> sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1, 
> java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\jre\lib\endorsed, 
> os.arch=amd64, 
> java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, 
> os.name=Windows 7, 
> sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252, 
> java.library.path=C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\bin;......, 
> sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, 
> os.version=6.1, 
> file.encoding=UTF-8, 
> sun.java.command=fromso.IsolatedBug, 
> java.home=C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\jre, 
> sun.arch.data.model=64, 
> user.language=en, 
> java.ext.dirs=C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\jre\lib\ext;C:\windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext,
>
> sun.boot.class.path=C:\Java8\jdk-1.8.0_01\jre\lib\resources.jar;......,
> java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, 
> file.separator=\, 
> java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, 
> sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, 
> sun.cpu.endian=little, 
> sun.desktop=windows, 
> sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
> }
> ```

Comment: I've readed through the posts, but I'm unable to figure out if or when a release (and in which version), will be shipped? So I can test it later.

Comment: The blog entry claims the problem is fixed too! And the fix will be in the release in March. `"UPDATE:
The bug was fixed. The cause was an over optimization of the hot spot compiler. So the fix will be part of the official JDK 8 release in March! So we can use the default methods in interfaces again with not being afraid of strange behaviour."`

Comment: @DanTemple That's however claimed by a blog, so I'd rather have the official source of it.

Comment: Also it is claimed that is surely fixed in the relese in March, however what I am wondering is if they are claiming that it is fixed now already?

Comment: The backport to 8 is [JDK-8032966](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8032966) and it seems to have been fixed in b127.

Comment: I'll be darned, I just tested and it is definitely reproducible in b129. Does not reproduce with `-Xint` though. This should be brought up with the developers as soon as possible. b129 is supposed to be the final release candidate!

Comment: @ntoskrnl I have actually filed a bug report earlier today haven't seen it anywhere around http://bugs.java.com yet though.

Comment: @skiwi Yeah, it takes at least a few days until they move it to the public bug repository (in some cases it could take months). It's often faster to contact them using the mailing lists. You can also discuss bugs on the lists, while there's no way to respond to a bug report unless you're an Oracle developer.

Comment: @assylias One thing to note is that the relationship of the classes and interfaces in my test case seem to be more complicated as in that particular bug, so that may have to do with it.

Comment: @assylias That is completely fine, the more attention, the better.

Comment: @Skiwi http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-dev/2014-February/012789.html

Comment: @skiwi It appeared as [JDK-8036100](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036100), and yes, it's a P1.

Comment: @skiwi ...and it's now also "fixed". There will be a new build soon. The fix was to disable an optimization called CHA for default methods. [JDK-8036153](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8036153) tracks a real fix for the underlying issue.

Comment: [Build b132](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) should contain the fix: http://download.java.net/jdk8/changes/jdk8-b132.html

Comment: @skiwi I'll be darned (again). You got a mention in the Java 8 GA announcement (last paragraph): http://mreinhold.org/blog/jdk8-ga